# Unable to login as test user when test in-App Purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I have implemented iTunes store in the app. As I have read in the apple docs you have to log out from your real Apple ID to test it with a test user. Im logged out now but when I want to buy from in-app I cant change my email. Its still the same as my real App store ID. I cant enter my test user email.

1. I have restore network settings
2. I have removed my iCloud account from the iphone
3. I have logged out from Settings>Store
4. I have restarted the phone.

But with No success. Any help ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anyone but I'm currently doing the same thing:

You sign out by:
Settings -> Store -> click Apple ID -> Click signout

If you only have one email address I suggest you use the '+' to make it look different when you register the test user:

Eg:
if your email is:
me@company.com
use this will go to the same address:
me+test@company.com

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this answer was accepted. It seems to just reiterate step #3 from the original question. Is it that the OP was using the same email address and the tip in the answer fixed things? Let's make this answer more clear by stating what fixed the problem.

Comment: Its been 18 months since I touched IOS development but if i remember correctly I'd seen exactly the same behaviour as the question. I think the app store was not letting me log out until I'd logged in with a different user.